# Combine PDFs with spaces in file names

Tags: linux, unix, pdf, pdftk

I have a directory with lots of PDFs that have spaces in their file names.

```
file 1.pdf
file 2.pdf
file 3.pdf
# And so on
```

I ran this command in that directory.

```
pdftk `ls -v` cat output combined-report.pdf
```

But the terminal spat out a bunch of errors like this.

```
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   file
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   1.pdf
```

How do I combine the PDFs using `pdftk` or any other package in Arch Linux? To clarify, I want to combine the files in the order printed by `ls -v`

Comment: You should read "[Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)"

Answer (score 2):

Just use a wildcard while creating combining the pdfs like:

`pdftk *.pdf cat output newfile.pdf`

Or else you could use something like this:

`pdftk file\ 1.pdf file\ 2.pdf cat output newfile.pdf`

Comment: Nah, because the order that command combines the PDFs in goes like "1, 10, 11, 12..." instead of "1, 2, 3...". I edited my question to clarify

Comment: Then, you can write a small bash script where you iterate over the files inside that directory... I could have done it for you... But I don't know bash that much. Rest good luck with that. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find . -name 'file*.pdf' -print0 | sort -z -V | xargs -0 -I{} pdftk {} cat output combined-report.pdf
```

or this:

```
ls -v file*.pdf | xargs -d'\n' -I{} pdftk {} cat output combined-report.pdf
```

In the first line, "-print0", "-z", and "-0" tell the corresponding command to use null as delimiter. The "-V" parameter for sort specifies "version sort" which I think should produce the sorting you wanted. Normally, the parameters that are piped are appended to the end of xargs. "-I{}" specifies a placeholder, "{}", that you can use to put them in the middle of the command.

The second line is similar, except that it takes parameter from "ls", and use newline '\n' as delimiter.

Note: there are potential problems with using "ls". See the link posted by @stephen-p.

Comment: In both cases the code creates a PDF that is a copy of the last PDF in the directory.

Comment: @Username Try to change the "*.pdf" to only match your input file. e.g. file*.pdf as in your example. Otherwise the wildcard expansion will also include combined-report.pdf that's created in the same directory.

Comment: Didn't realize the asterisk became a markup for italic in my last comment. I edited the answer to be more precise about input filenames.